# Export material with Blender for obj

Tags: materials

I'm completely new to Blender and I have to do an apparently simple thing. Open a blender file and export it as .obj with its .mtl file.
When I look at the model with Material "view" everything is ok (colored as I want) [image] when I look with Solid "view" everything is grey
[image]
Now I go to export .obj and I select "Write Materials" creating the .mtl file.
Unfortunately, all the created materials are:

```
newmtl Material.007
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

that is something like grey. How can I export the true materials?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: ok, as far as I understood I have to redefine the materials in my .mtl file since blender is not able to export them. Is this the answer?

Comment: What is the purpose of this OBJ file? Do you really need material information?

Comment: I have to import the 3D model of the car in another program to make some videos. Without the material file the car looks grey. Actually, I have seen that modifying manually the .mtl file makes the final car acceptable, could not be the best solution but is enough for the moment.